# Re-arrange a table per group

Tags: r, aggregate

I work with R and I have this data:

```
   data <- structure(list(Col1 = 1:9, Col2 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Administrative ", "National", 
"Regional"), class = "factor"), Col3 = structure(c(NA, 3L, 4L, 
NA, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("bike", "boat", "car", "truck"
), class = "factor"), Col4 = c(56L, 65L, 58L, 62L, 24L, 25L, 
120L, 89L, 468L), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    X.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Col1", 
"Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "X", "X.1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I would like to re-arrange it to see what is available or nor. The output would look like this:

```
    result <- structure(list(Col1 = c(1L, 4L, 5L), Col2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
3L), .Label = c("Administrative ", "National", "Regional"), class = "factor"), 
    car = c(1L, 0L, 1L), truck = c(1L, 0L, 1L), boat = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L), bike = c(0L, 0L, 1L)), .Names = c("Col1", "Col2", 
"car", "truck", "boat", "bike"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

I have tried with aggregate but I am still far from the result. Help would be

```
t <- aggregate(data$Col2, by=list(data$Col3), c)
```

Help is welcome!

Comment: Please also add in the language you are working with, makes it easier to find help.

Comment: Edited! It was in the topic title :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `data.table` with `length` as `fun.aggregate`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), Col2~ Col3, length)[, 1:5, with = FALSE]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea using base R,

```
#convert to character
data[2:3] <- lapply(data[2:3], as.character)

#get unique elements to tabulate
i1 <- unique(data$Col3)
i1 <- i1[!is.na(i1)]


setNames(data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data$Col3, data$Col2), function(i) 
                                          as.integer(match(i1, i, nomatch = 0) > 0)))), i1)
```

which gives,

> ```
>                car truck boat bike
> Administrative    0     0    0    0
> National          1     1    0    0
> Regional          1     1    1    1
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a dplyr solution if you are interested, though akrun's solution seems more concise:

```
library(tidyverse)

result <- data %>%
  group_by(Col2, Col3) %>%
  summarise(tot = sum(Col4)) %>%
  mutate(bool = if_else(tot > 0, 1, 0)) %>%
  select(Col2, Col3, bool) %>%
  spread(key = Col3, value = bool, fill = 0) %>%
  select(-`<NA>`)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R method using `table` and some coercion.

```
(table(data$Col2, data$Col3) > 0) + 0L

                  bike boat car truck
  Administrative     0    0   0     0
  National           0    0   1     1
  Regional           1    1   1     1
```

`table` counts the instances, returning 0 for the NAs. We then coerce to logical with `> 0` to drop values greater than 1 and back to integer with `+ 0L`.